# Calling smart contracts function with struct params

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Calling The function from another smart contract:

```
 (bool success, bytes memory data) = ADDRESS
            .call(
                abi.encodeWithSignature(
                    "update(uint256, profile)",
                    tokenId,
                    Profile("", "", "", "")
                )
            );
```

The called function:

```
   function update(
        uint256 tokenId,
        Profile memory profile
    ) public authorise(tokenId) {
        array[tokenId] = profile;
    }
```

It fails when I call the function via call from another function. Maybe I  did something wrong on the params. Can someone help me?

Comment: It seems that the revert is caused by some failed condition in the `authorise` modifier. Can you share it as well?

Comment: Yeah error was in Constructor. I fixed it

Comment: Great. Please consider posting the solution as an answer to your own question, so that others with the same or similar issue are able to find the solution as well.

Comment: My problem was that I used call and not delegate call. On the authorise function it checked if this the sender is the owner of the token. I splitted it to 2 contracts so its more efficient and gas fees lower. Bc if I did everything in one it was a bit very expensive and slow